# ifnum and expansion of macro argument

Tags: macros, expansion

Here is a problem that has been puzzling me for a few days.
Basically, I try to parse strings and test their symbols one by one to define whether they are or not numbers (in order to achieve some more complicated treatment, beyond this topic).

The macros `\@neByOne`, `\aux@neByOne`, `\c@untunlessnil` and `\gobblechar` split the string. For each symbol, the macro `\testSymbol` is called and is meant to tell if it is a number.

The problem: when called directly, `\testSymbol` returns the expected result. But when called by `\c@untunlessnil`, the test fails. In fact, the parameter `#1` is not seen as a number by `\ifnum`.
Below are my files and the results I get.

Thank you for your help.

Content of `myExtension.sty`

```
\def\testSymbol#1{%
     \ifnum0<0#1\relax%
        <<#1>> is a number\\
    \else%
        <<#1>> is a NOT number\\
    \fi%
}


\def\gobblechar{\let\ch@r= }
\def\c@untunlessnil{%
    \ifx\ch@r\nil%
        \let\next=\relax%
    \else%
        \testSymbol\ch@r%
        \let\next=\aux@neByOne%
    \fi\next
}
\def\aux@neByOne{\afterassignment\c@untunlessnil\gobblechar}
\def\@neByOne#1{\edef\xx{#1}\expandafter\aux@neByOne\xx\nil}


\def\test#1{BEGIN\\\@neByOne{#1}END\\}
```

Content of `myMainFile.tex` :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{myExtension}

\begin{document}
\test{123}
\testSymbol{1}
\testSymbol{2}
\testSymbol{3}
```

The output I get:

```
BEGIN
«1» is a NOT number
«2» is a NOT number
«3» is a NOT number
END
«1» is a number
«2» is a number
«3» is a number
```

Comment: Do you have to test individual numbers in `123`, or can you just test `123` as a whole?

Comment: Easy: if you say `\let\next=1`, then `\ifnum0<0\next` returns false, because `\next` is not expandable.

Comment: @Werner: I have to test individual characters as some of them may not be numeric.

Comment: @egreg: I am sorry but I do not understand what you mean. I have to admit that the "splitting" macros are not from me thus I do not get exactly how they work. Thank you

Comment: @egreg: I thought that `#1` was `\ch@r` which expands well...

Comment: `\ch@r` is defined by `\let` so is typically not expandable, It is only expandable if the token that it is defined to be is already expandable. `\let\ch@r=1` does not make it expand to 1, that would be `\def\ch@r{1}`

Comment: it's a bad idea to use internal macro names of the form `\c@foo` as that is the internal name of the counter `foo`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: fine. But why does `#1` expands in the sentence `<<#1>> is a NOT number`? I definitely do not understand that.

Comment: `#1` doesn't  _expand_  to anything, but if it is `2` then `\edef\xx{#1}\expandafter\aux@neByOne\xx` is just a long way of writing `\aux@neByOne#1` which is the same as  `\aux@neByOne2`  but you never use the token `2` again you use `\let\ch@r=2` and then use `\ch@r`  which does not expand to 2, it is just let-equal to 2.

Comment: fine. Thank you. I will try to find another way to do what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a test such as the following

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\def\test#1{\@tfor\tmp:=#1\do{%
<<\tmp>>
\ifcat1\expandafter\noexpand\tmp
  \ifnum\expandafter`\tmp>47
    \ifnum\expandafter`\tmp<58
      IS
    \else
      IS NOT
    \fi
  \else
    IS NOT
  \fi
\else
IS NOT
\fi
a number\par
}}

\begin{document}
\test{123}
\test{1}
\test{2}
\test{3}
\test{4abc5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks good! I didn't know the `\@tfor` command.

Comment: Now, what if I want to use something like that? : `\def\myString{a123b}\test\myString`

Comment: @zigma12 `\expandafter\test\expandafter{\mystring}`

Comment: Many thanks. I tried to put some `\expandafter` but not the right way. Please, tell me if I get it right: the 2nd `\expandafter` applies to the opening (and so closing) brace?

Comment: @zigma12 no the second `\expandafter` expands `\mystring`, the first `\expandafter` expands the second `\expandafter`.

Comment: yes it expands `\myString` by jumping over `{`. That what I meant